# Install linux on existing partition

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I was wondering if it is possible to install a linux based distro to an existing partition, without moving any files. An example is how Slax can be installed: https://www.slax.org/en/starting.php.

Comment: As long as it's not another linux install, and the old files won't conflict, then I *think* you can just copy the required files over + add / modify a bootloader like grub.

Comment: @Xen2050, Can I install it within a directory ?

Comment: Linux generally needs files in the right places in `/`, if you can get `/` to mount somewhere else it might work, I'm not positive